# Converting Text to Number and Then Multiplying Fails in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have three data frames each with one column and same length with the following example data:

```
df1 = c(1, 2, 3)
df2 = c('a', 'b', 'a')
df3 = c(2, 3, 4)
```

I convert all "a" values in df2 to 100 and all "b" values in df2 to -100 using the following code:

```
df2[df2 == "a"] <- as.numeric(100)
df2[df2 == "b"] <- as.numeric(-100)
```

Then I create df4 by multiplying df1, df2, and df3 using this code:

```
df4 <- (df1 * df2 * df3)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What am I doing wrong? I can multiply df1 and df3 without issue, it is only when I add df2 that a problem results. If I look to average df2 I get that the average is "NA_real_", which leads me to believe that my numeric values are not being treated as numbers. Thanks!

Comment: The first block isn't valid R code. Are `a` and `b` objects in your environment, or should that be a vector of strings?

Comment: There is an edit in queue for that modification ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It don't work because you change the value of df2 one by one and therefore as long as there is a character value in it, every numeric value is set as.character in the vector.

Here is a correction of your code, where I change the whole vector in numeric after your transformation

```
df1 = c(1, 2, 3)
df2 = c('a','b', 'a')
df3 = c(2, 3, 4)

df2[df2 == "a"] <- as.numeric(100)
df2[df2 == "b"] <- as.numeric(-100)

df2 ; class(df2)
# [1] "100"  "-100" "100" 
# [1] "character"
df2 = as.numeric(df2)
df2 ; class(df2)
# [1]  100 -100  100
# [1] "numeric"

df4 <- (df1 * df2 * df3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I would agree with the thesis, but when I convert df2 to numeric, I get this error: "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Comment: Well then what is the class of your df2 object ? Because this code is okay, so maybe you don't have the save df2 object as us.

Comment: Well this is a problem because at you presented your question, I assumed it was a vector. I think you are in trouble because you have a dataframe with factors in it...What happens with `str(df2)` and `summary(df2)`

Comment: Okay, I got it to run by explicitly calling out the column name in the df2, by saying `df2$df2 <- as.numeric(df2$df2)` not sure why that worked, but it did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, at least it works. I don't get it also, but I think you may need to work with vectors rather than data.frames with one row. It's easier to figure it out ;)

(If the answer is okay, don't forget to mark the question as answered)

Answer (score 1):

the thing is that you re converting to numeric just one element per time in a character vector, thus you cannot have 2 different types of elements inside the same vector, and it stays a character type.

```
df2 <- as.numeric(df2)
df4 <- (df1 * df2 * df3)
```